# My structure in Firebase db. Is that proper hierarchy?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I would like to constract proper structure for an app which shows a list of companies. When I tap on one company, the app shows phone numbers in other view. Could somebody advise me with my structure?

```
 {
  "companies" : {
    "c1" : {
      "name" : "Secure Home LLP",
      "subject" : "Security"
    }
  },
  "phones" : {
    "c1" : {
      "p1" : {
        "name" : "Check point",
        "phone" : "201-478-4600"
      },
      "p2" : {
        "name" : "Dispatcher",
        "phone" : "201-478-4678"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: My structure]

Answer (score -1):

The structure that you have given will be a great tiring work while parsing into the different data.

This following structure will be a better Option. You can parse into the phone numbers just by getting into the company keys. Here it is `c1, c1`

```
 {
  "companies" : {
    "c1" : {
      "name" : "Secure Home LLP",
      "subject" : "Security",
      "p1" : {
          "name" : "Check point",
          "phone" : "201-478-4600"
          },
      },
    "c2" : {
      "name": "neCompanyName",
      "subject" : "Design",
      "p2" : {
          "name" : "Dispatcher",
          "phone" : "201-478-4678"
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! But main point here is that, company may have a few phone numbers. So that, it makes deep hierarchy. At least for one level. I read Firebase examples of db structure and did find similar example. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data